# Interpreting p-value from GLMMTMB model

Tags: p-value, interpretation, glmm, lsmeans, glmmtmb

I'm analyzing count data from an experiment, where I want to study whether colonies of ants with different ratios (0, 50 100) of infected workers have different foraging activities. I am using the forager count as the response variable and the infection ratio as a factor. Because the colonies are sub-colonies from original nests, I've added original colony as a random factor as well as adding a random factor of observation time within the sub-colony ID to account for pseudoreplication.

I've built a model using GLMMTMB

```
fc.a4 <- glmmTMB(Foragers~PerInfected + (1|Colony)+(1|Box/Time), data = df.choice, family=nbinom1)
```

Which gives me the output:

```
> summary(fc.a4)
 Family: nbinom1  ( log )
Formula:          Foragers ~ PerInfected + (1 | Colony) + (1 | Box/Time)
Data: df.choice

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   727.0    761.6   -356.5    713.0     1024 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Colony   (Intercept) 4.092e-09 6.397e-05
 Time:Box (Intercept) 3.556e-07 5.963e-04
 Box      (Intercept) 7.227e-01 8.501e-01
Number of obs: 1031, groups:  Colony, 19; Time:Box, 180; Box, 45

Dispersion parameter for nbinom1 family (): 0.17 

Conditional model:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -3.1154     0.3426  -9.093   <2e-16 ***
PerInfected50    0.6361     0.4430   1.436    0.151    
PerInfected100   0.9457     0.4275   2.212    0.027 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I'm a relative beginner with statistics with R, but how I interpret this according to this article (https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-066/RJ-2017-066.pdf) the output shows that the p value according to the Wald Z statistic would show, that the difference between 0 percent infected and 100 percent infected would be significant (0.027).

But should I instead use emmeans to make a pairwise comparison with a tukey's p value adjustment to get the p-value, since according to some sources the Wald Z statistic isn't always a good way to get significances between factors?

Any input would be highly appreciated (also whether the code to my model is correct), as I would like to understand this in more detail, especially because I don't have a statistical background and I wouldn't want to erroneously interpret results.

Comment: It depends in part on your research goals, but from what I can tell, it is of interest to compare all three infection levels. By doing the Tukey comparisons, you see all three comparisons, whereas you don't see estimates of one of them in the regression summary. And they are multiplicity-adjusted, which is appropriate. Note however that all those comparisons will be Wald tests. I think the concern you mention may be that it's better to look at those individual comparisons rather than the omnibus Wald test for the effects of the factor in question.

Comment: Thank you @RussLenth for your input! Yes, optimally I would like to compare all infection levels.